# ld: warning: ignoring file

Tags: c, file

```
ld: warning: ignoring file file, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x70 0x6F 0x6A 0x61 0x0A 0x6F 0x64 0x6F 0x64 0x6F 0x6B 0x64 0x6F 0x6B 0x64 0x6F ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): file
```

This is my error after compile the program. In my program I want to print just the 80 characters on a file, named `file`.

This is my program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    print_80_char(char *path)
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    char *buf;

    fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
    buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);
    i = 0;
    while (buf[i] <= 79)
    {
        read(fd, buf, 80);
        printf("%c", buf[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

and my main is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_80_char(char *path);

int main()
{
    print_80_char("file");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `file` appears to be a text file containing ASCII data, why are you trying to link to it? What is the command you're using to compile and link?

Comment: I use gcc (with flags) -Werror -Wextra -Wall main.c print_80_char.c file

Comment: I've remove the "file" for my compilation.